# Sanitize/escape argument that's going into a SSH command

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

What do I need to do to properly sanitize/escape a parameter that is being entered into a programmatic SSH command?

For example, the path parameter -

```
public boolean exists(String path) {

    try {
        ChannelExec c = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

        //Here *** would like to be sure that the path is completely valid
        c.setCommand("[ -f " + path + " ] && echo \"File exists\" || echo \"File does not exists\"");

        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        c.connect();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        IOUtils.copy(in, out);

        in.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println(out.toString("UTF-8"));
        c.disconnect();

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

The reason it is unsafe is that the path parameter can come from a user uploaded file.  A malicious user could technically upload a file w/ an invalid filename.  Although I can check for this beforehand (which I'm doing) I'd also like to check for it here too.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "invalid", I suppose.

Comment: Malicious.  Making sure it isn't doing "SSH injection" per se...

Comment: Just backslash everything that isn't "normal" so it's for-sure a filename, I guess? Particularly semi-colons, for sure.

Comment: Yea, I think that's the approach I'm going to take.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good idea here would be to make sure it is passed as a single parameter to `[`, and not multiple ones (or even multiple commands). So simply wrap it in `'`, and replace any `'` inside the string by `'\''`.

```
private String escape(String s) {
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'";
}
```

You also can use `'` instead of `\"` for the `echo` part of the command, as long as you don't need variable expansion on the server side (and there are no variables in these strings):

```
c.setCommand("[ -f " + escape(path) + " ] && " +
              "echo 'File exists' || echo 'File does not exist'");
```

(Note that I also did a tiny grammar fix.)

Comment: I like where this is going... very much appreciate the answer.  It's returning back that the file does not exist though.  I'm going to keep tinkering with it though and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Also why use `'\''` instead of escaping with just `\'`?

Comment: I got this quoting mechanism from [this Unix & Linux question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/5779), it explains it nicely. *The single quote of Bourne-like shells is actually literal (which means you can not use it to quote a single quote character itself).*

Comment: Got it working, it was my path... it doesn't like the tilde character in the file path which isn't a concern.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah, yes, `~` has different meanings in a `'`-quoted string than in a un-quoted word (where it will be expanded).